# Binding to ChoiceList Display Name in Lightswitch with Telerik Grid

Tags: telerik, visual-studio-lightswitch, radgridview

I have swapped the core Lightswitch 2011 data grid control with the latest Telerik Silverlight RadGridView control.

As per their tutorials, I bind the grid columns as per normal.

However, in the core Lightswitch datagrid, if you bind to a string field that is a ChoiceList (e.g. Project Status - Value = 1, DisplayName = "In Progress") then it automatically shows the Display NAme (e.g. "IN Progress").

But in the Telerik RadGridView it shows the VALUE, not the DisplayName (e.g. 1 in the example above).

Here is the DataMemberBinding expression I use in the XAML customer control:

I assume the core Lightswitch DataGrid is getting it from the query somehow - I assumed it would be something like 
Binding ProjectStatus.DisplayName but this does not work... (See screenshot)

[image]

```
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  ShowColumnWhenGrouped="False"
                                     Width="SizeToHeader"
                                     CellStyle="{StaticResource FormLabelValueTextStyle}"
                                     DataMemberBinding="{Binding ProjectStatus}">
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderCellTextBlockStyle}"
                           Text="Project Status" />
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
        </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</Controls:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Choice Lists* are a LightSwitch concept, they're stored in the lsml file (one of the reasons I don't use them), so I'm not surprised that it's not available if you're using a non-LS datagrid.

The way around this would be to use an actual lookup *table* instead of the *choice list*. Then you'd be able to bind to the entity's properties.

Comment: Thanks - I took your suggestion as Lookup tables are more flexible anyway and the user can add data at run time.

Comment: You're welcome Rodney. And your reasons are the same as why I prefer lookup tables to choice lists.